# Sort the numpy matrix by the minimum values and display minimum values on the diagonal of matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

No matter how the other elements are positioned, is important only the values along the diagonal.

For example I have matrix:

```
matrix = [[1, 3, 2],
          [2, 5, -9],
          [3, 4, 6]]
```

What I want to achieve is something the same as:

```
[[-9, 3, 2],
 [6, 1, 5],
 [3, 4, 2]]
```

I have tried:

```
>>> np_matrix = np.array(matrix)
>>> np_matrix.diagonal()
array([1, 5, 6])

>>> np.sort(np_matrix)
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [-9,  2,  5],
       [ 3,  4,  6]])
```

I think that I can get something from these methods, but I can not figure out how to make them work together. I appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: Is your matrix always 3x3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you want. But maybe something like

```
sorted = np.sort(matrix, axis=None) #sorts flattened matrix
```

Now you have reshape it, and then change the diagonal elements with the first row:

```
sorted.shape = matrix.shape
for i in xrange(1, matrix.shape[0]):  # first element already in order
     sorted[0, i], sorted[i, i] = sorted[i, i], sorted[0, i]
```

But honestly I would first question if that really is what you want. It doesn't seem really useful to me. Isn't it maybe enough to get an array with the smallest elements

`diag_lowest = np.sort(matrix, axis=None)[:matrix.shape[0]]`

and keep the matrix as it is.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer `sorted.shape = matrix.shape` rather than using `ndarray.reshape`?

Comment: I don't really know. The assignment seems for me pretty pythonic, as this is the way `setters` are implemented. But I honestly don't know, I think under the hood it will be pretty mush the same, just that `reshape` offers additional `order` settings. 
Probably `sorted.shape = ...`, `np.reshape(sroted, ...)` and `sorted.reshape(...)` all do the same, unless you use the `order` argument.

Comment: A short search gave me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856375/when-to-use-shape-and-when-to-use-reshape.
So `reshape` might create a copy, whereas `shape = ` would result in an error if it is not possible to create a view.

Comment: Thanks, it works. The only thing you have a small bug in your code, it must be sorted[0,i], sorted[i,i] = sorted[i,i], sorted[0,i]