# Reshaping a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following NumPy array,

```
[[date1,num1],[date2,num2],[date3,num3],[date4,num4]]
```

I want to divide it as follows:

```
[ [ [date1,num1],[date2,num2] ] , [ [date3,num3],[date4,num4] ] ]
```

Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [reshape an array in numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476415/reshape-an-array-in-numpy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = np.array([['date1','num1'],['date2','num2'],['date3','num3'],['date4','num4']])

a.reshape((2,2,2))
array([[['date1', 'num1'],
    ['date2', 'num2']],

   [['date3', 'num3'],
    ['date4', 'num4']]])
```

Comment: i am a lil confused.... what if my array is [[date1,num1],[date2,num2],[date3,num3],[date4,num4],[date5,[num5],[date6],[num6]].. what parameter should i change?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Numpy's [reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) method and the `-1` argument to reshape arrays of arbitrary length between the two forms you specify. Like so:

```
import numpy as np

#Generate an array of the form you specify of arbitrary length
arraylen = 10
a        = np.array([ ['date'+str(i),'num'+str(i)] for i in range(arraylen*2)])

#Reshape the array per your specifications
a.reshape((-1,2,2))
```

Gives

```
array([[['date0', 'num0'],
        ['date1', 'num1']],

       [['date2', 'num2'],
        ['date3', 'num3']],
        ...
```