# sklearn issue: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples when doing regression

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

this question seems to have been asked before, but I can't seem to comment for further clarification on the accepted answer and I couldn't figure out the solution provided.

I am trying to learn how to use sklearn with my own data. I essentially just got the annual % change in GDP for 2 different countries over the past 100 years. I am just trying to learn using a single variable for now. What I am essentially trying to do is use sklearn to predict what the GDP % change for country A will be given the percentage change in country B's GDP.

The problem is that I receive an error saying:

> ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [  1
>   107]

Here is my code:

```
import sklearn.linear_model as lm
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


def bytespdate2num(fmt, encoding='utf-8'):#function to convert bytes to string for the dates.
    strconverter = mdates.strpdate2num(fmt)
    def bytesconverter(b):
        s = b.decode(encoding)
        return strconverter(s)
    return bytesconverter

dataCSV = open('combined_data.csv')

comb_data = []

for line in dataCSV:
    comb_data.append(line)

date, chngdpchange, ausgdpchange = np.loadtxt(comb_data, delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters={0: bytespdate2num('%d/%m/%Y')})


chntrain = chngdpchange[:-1]
chntest = chngdpchange[-1:]

austrain = ausgdpchange[:-1]
austest = ausgdpchange[-1:]

regr = lm.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(chntrain, austrain)

print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)

print("Residual sum of squares: %.2f"
      % np.mean((regr.predict(chntest) - austest) ** 2))

print('Variance score: %.2f' % regr.score(chntest, austest))

plt.scatter(chntest, austest,  color='black')
plt.plot(chntest, regr.predict(chntest), color='blue')

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

What am I doing wrong? I essentially tried to apply the sklearn tutorial (They used some diabetes data set) to my own simple data. My data just contains the date, country A's % change in GDP for that specific year, and country B's % change in GDP for that same year.

I tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813044/sklearn-found-arrays-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-when-calling-linearre) and [here (basically trying to find more out about the solution in the first link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476415/reshape-an-array-in-numpy), but just receive the exact same error.

Here is the full traceback in case you want to see it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\My Stuff\Dropbox\Python\Python projects\test regression\tester.py", line 34, in <module>
    regr.fit(chntrain, austrain)
  File "D:\Programs\Installed\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 376, in fit
    y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)
  File "D:\Programs\Installed\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 454, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "D:\Programs\Installed\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 174, in check_consistent_length
    "%s" % str(uniques))
ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [  1 107]
```

Comment: Check the shapes of `chntrain` and `austrain` before splitting into training/test sets. They should have the same shape; the error seems to be indicating that the sizes are not the same

Comment: How can I do that? I've been googling but every solution that let's me reshape or find the shape just gives the error:

IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: for e.g. `print chngdpchange.shape, ausgdpchange.shape`

Answer (score 6):

In fit(X,y),the input parameter X is supposed to be a 2-D array. But if X in your data is only one-dimension, you can just reshape it into a 2-D array like this:`regr.fit(chntrain_X.reshape(len(chntrain_X), 1), chntrain_Y)`

Answer (score 0):

```
regr.fit(chntrain, austrain)
```

This doesn't look right. The first parameter to `fit` should be an `X`, which refers to a feature vector. The second parameter should be a `y`, which is the correct answers (targets) vector associated with `X`.

For example, if you have GDP, you might have:

```
X[0] = [43, 23, 52] -> y[0] = 5
# meaning the first year had the features [43, 23, 52] (I just made them up)
# and the change that year was 5
```

Judging by your names, both `chntrain` and `austrain` are feature vectors. Judging by how you load your data, maybe the last column is the target?

Maybe you need to do something like:

```
chntrain_X, chntrain_y = chntrain[:, :-1], chntrain[:, -1]
# you can do the same with austrain and concatenate them or test on them if this part works
regr.fit(chntrain_X, chntrain_y)
```

But we can't tell without knowing the exact storage format of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `chntrain` to a 2-D array instead of 1-D, i.e. reshape to `(len(chntrain), 1)`.

For prediction, also change `chntest` to a 2-D array.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having similar problems to you and have found a solution.

Where you have the following error:

```
ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [  1 107]
```

The [  1 107] part is basically saying that your array is the wrong way around. Sklearn thinks you have 107 columns of data with 1 row.

To fix this try transposing the X data like so:

```
chntrain.T
```

The re-run your fit:

```
regr.fit(chntrain, austrain)
```

Depending on what your "austrain" data looks like you may need to transpose this too.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `np.newaxis` as well. The example can be `X = X[:, np.newaxis]`. I found the method at [Logistic function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_logistic.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-logistic-py)