# Trouble fitting a polynomial regression curve in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, polynomials

I am new to sklearn and I have an appropriately simple task: given a scatter plot of 15 dots, I need to

1. Take 11 of them as my 'training sample',
2. Fit a polynomial curve of degree 3 through these 11 dots;
3. Plot the resulting polynomial curve over the 15 dots.

But I got stuck at the second step.

This is the data plot:

```
%matplotlib notebook

import numpy as np from sklearn.model_selection 
import train_test_split from sklearn.linear_model 
import LinearRegression from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

np.random.seed(0) 
n = 15 
x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5 
y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)

plt.figure() plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, label='training data') 
plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, label='test data') 
plt.legend(loc=4);
```

I then take the 11 points in `X_train` and transform them with a poly features of degree 3 as follow:

```
degrees = 3
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree)

X_train_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
```

Then I try to fit a line through the transformed points (note: `X_train_poly.size` = 364).

```
linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train_poly, y_train)
```

and I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 11]
```

I have read various questions that address similar and often more complex problems (e.g. [Multivariate (polynomial) best fit curve in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856206/multivariate-polynomial-best-fit-curve-in-python)), but I could not extract a solution from them.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097392/sklearn-issue-found-arrays-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-when-doing-regr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the dimension in the X_train and y_train.  It is a single-dimension array so it is treating each of the X records as a separate variable.

Using the .reshape command as follows should do the trick:

```
# reshape data to have 11 records rather than 11 columns
X_trainT     = X_train.reshape(11,1)
y_trainT     = y_train.reshape(11,1)

# create polynomial features on the single va
poly         = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
X_train_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_trainT)

print (X_train_poly.shape)
# 

linreg       = LinearRegression().fit(X_train_poly, y_trainT)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error basically mean your `X_train_poly` and `y_train` doesn't match, where your `X_train_poly` has only 1 set of x and your `y_train` has 11 values. I'm not quite sure what you want, but I guess the polynomial features were not generated in the way you want. What your code currently doing is to generated the degree-3 polynomial features for a single 11-dimension point.

I think you want to generated the degree-3 polynomial features for every points (actually every x) of your 11 points. You can use a loop or list comprehension to do that:

```
X_train_poly = poly.fit_transform([[i] for i in X_train])
X_train_poly.shape
# (11, 4)
```

Now you can see your `X_train_poly` has 11 points where each point is 4-dimension, rather than a single 364-dimension point. This new `X_train_poly` matches the shape of `y_train` and the regression may give you what you want:

```
linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train_poly, y_train)
linreg.coef_
# array([ 0.        , -0.79802899,  0.2120088 , -0.01285893])
```