# How does numpy.swapaxes work?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I created a sample array:

```
a = np.arange(18).reshape(9,2)
```

On printing, I get this as output:

```
[[ 0  1]
[ 2  3]
[ 4  5]
[ 6  7]
[ 8  9]
[10 11]
[12 13]
[14 15]
[16 17]]
```

On executing this reshaping:

```
b = a.reshape(2,3,3).swapaxes(0,2)
```

I get:

```
[[[ 0  9]
[ 3 12]
[ 6 15]]

[[ 1 10]
[ 4 13]
[ 7 16]]

[[ 2 11]
[ 5 14]
[ 8 17]]]
```

I went through this question, but it does not solve my problem.

[Reshape an array in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476415/reshape-an-array-in-numpy)

The documentation is not useful either.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html

I need to know how the swapping is working(which is x-axis, y-axis, z-axis). A diagrammatic explanation would be most helpful.

Comment: Do you understand what transpose does to a 2d array?

Comment: I understand transpose.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Start with the reshape

```
In [322]: a = np.arange(18).reshape(2,3,3)
In [323]: a
Out[323]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

This displays as 2 planes, and each plane is a 3x3.  Is that part clear?  The fact that the array was shaped (9,2) at one point isn't significant.  Reshaping doesn't change the order of elements.

Apply the `swapaxes`. Shape is now (3,3,2).  3 planes, each is 3x2.  This particular swap is the same as a transpose

```
np.arange(18).reshape(2,3,3).transpose(2,1,0)
```

The middle axis is unchanged.  There are still columns of [0,3,6], [9,12,15], etc.

It may be easier to visualize the change with 3 different sized axes

```
In [335]: a=np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)
In [336]: a
Out[336]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
In [337]: a.swapaxes(0,2)
Out[337]: 
array([[[ 0, 12],
        [ 4, 16],
        [ 8, 20]],

       [[ 1, 13],
        [ 5, 17],
        [ 9, 21]],

       [[ 2, 14],
        [ 6, 18],
        [10, 22]],

       [[ 3, 15],
        [ 7, 19],
        [11, 23]]])
```

Notice what happens when I flatten the array

```
In [338]: a.swapaxes(0,2).ravel()
Out[338]: 
array([ 0, 12,  4, 16,  8, 20,  1, 13,  5, 17,  9, 21,  2, 14,  6, 18, 10,
       22,  3, 15,  7, 19, 11, 23])
```

the order of terms has been shuffled.  As created it was [0,1,2,3...].  Now the `1` is the 6th term (2x3).

Under the covers `numpy` actually performs the swap or transpose by changing `shape`, `strides` and `order`, without changing the data buffer (i.e. it's a view).  But further reshaping, including raveling, forces it to make a copy.  But that might be more confusing than helpful at this stage.

In `numpy` axes are numbered.  Terms like x,y,z or planes, rows, columns may help you map those on to constructs that you  can visualize, but they aren't 'built-in'.  Describing the swap or transpose in words is tricky.

Comment: thank you. I understand now. the `strides` and `order` part is confusing, so I'll leave that for later. But I don't understand the connection between `swap` and `transpose`. I've learnt that only a square matrix can be transposed and that again results in 3*3 matrix. But the `swap` will result in 3*2 matrix, which I don't understand how it's related to transpose.

Comment: In `numpy` transpose works with any shape array.  It's not restricted to square ones, or even 2d ones.  If `x` is (2,3), the `x.T` and `x.swapaxes(0,1)` do the same thing.

Answer (score 41):

Here is my understanding of `swapaxes`

Suppose you have an array

```py
In [1]: arr = np.arange(16).reshape((2, 2, 4))

In [2]: arr
Out[2]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]]])
```

And the shape of `arr` is `(2, 2, 4)`, for the value `7`, you can get the value by

```
In [3]: arr[0, 1, 3]
Out[3]: 7
```

There are 3 axes 0, 1 and 2, now, we swap axis 0 and 2

```
In [4]: arr_swap = arr.swapaxes(0, 2)

In [5]: arr_swap
Out[5]: 
array([[[ 0,  8],
        [ 4, 12]],

       [[ 1,  9],
        [ 5, 13]],

       [[ 2, 10],
        [ 6, 14]],

       [[ 3, 11],
        [ 7, 15]]])
```

And as you can guess, the index of `7` is `(3, 1, 0)`, with axis `1` unchanged,

```
In [6]: arr_swap[3, 1, 0]
Out[6]: 7
```

So, now from the perspective of the index, swapping axis is just change the index of values. For example

```
In [7]: arr[0, 0, 1]
Out[7]: 1

In [8]: arr_swap[1, 0, 0]
Out[8]: 1

In [9]: arr[0, 1, 2]
Out[9]: 6

In [9]: arr_swap[2, 1, 0]
Out[9]: 6
```

So, if you feel difficult to get the swapped-axis array, just change the index, say `arr_swap[2, 1, 0] = arr[0, 1, 2]`.

Comment: you're way of thinking  is genius. I was just struggling for 4 hrs straight  but now i got the whole math.

Comment: @Vicrobot I am glad you like it.

Comment: you made it simple for us to understand, Thank you so much.

Comment: @AlphaGreen I am very glad to hear that my answer is easy for you to understand `swapaxes`

Comment: really appreciate bud you made it very easy to understand especially last few lines

Comment: @zaheerahmad I am glad you enjoy it.

Comment: @GaneshTata I am glad you like it.