# numpy: fastest way to change image shape from 224 x 224 x 3 to 3 x 224 x 224

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I am going to use Keras pretrained Inception V3 model. After preprocessing the image shape is 224 x 224 x 3. But the input to the Keras Inception V3 model is (?, 3 , ?, ?), that is after batch size comes the channel. So I did array reshape. But this makes the whole thing super slow and eats up memory I am not sure why.

Note: When the image shape was 224, 224, 3 it works fine on a simple CNN. But 3, 224, 224 fed to the simple CNN made things super slow and memory overflow.

This is my code:

```
def get_image_preprocessed(image_name):
    im = Image.open(image_name)
    im = np.asarray(im)
    im = im/float(255)
    im = im.reshape(3,224,224) #this changes 224,224,3 to 3,224,224
    return im
```

This is the input tensor shape

> tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 3, ?, ?) dtype=float32

More Information:

Model-

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3,224, 224), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

Generator Function-

```
def generator(save_dir_path, encoding_list, batch_size, image_size):
    # Create empty arrays to contain batch of features and labels#
    batch_features = np.zeros((batch_size, 3, image_size, image_size))
    batch_labels = np.zeros((batch_size,len(encoding_list)))
    image_list= [file for file in os.listdir(save_dir_path) if (file.endswith('.jpeg') or file.endswith('.-'))]
    while True:
        for i in range(batch_size):
            # choose random index in features
            image_name= random.choice(image_list)
            batch_features[i] = get_image_preprocessed(save_dir_path, image_name)
            batch_labels[i] = np.asarray(get_encoding(encoding_list, image_name.split('_')[0]))
        yield batch_features, batch_labels
```

Comment: This looks like a `transpose` problem, not a `reshape` one.  The `3` should continue to represent the channels, and the `224,224` the image shape.

Comment: i did, the problem did not resolved. i have added more information here.

Comment: The problem is the backend. You need to read the documentation for the correct use of this model.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`.transpose`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) for this with:

```
im = im.transpose(2,0,1)
```

So from now on, the old third index (`2`) is the first index, the old first index (`0`) is the second index, and the old second index (`1`) is the third index.

So if you access `im[i,j,k]` is is like you had accessed `im[j,k,i]` *before* the transpose.

Comment: I just did transpose, the problem is still there. when using 224,224,3 it is taking around 300MB but when 3,224,224 it is taking 4.4GB. This is crazy.

Comment: @sjishan: that is close to impossible, since `transpose` does *not* create a new array, it creates a *view*. Usually that would take ~100 bytes .

Comment: Hi Yes. I figured it out, this is not the issue with `transpose` or `reshape`.

224,224,3 creates 1,910,851  parameters. 3,224,224 creating   205,533,091 parameters. So that's overflowing the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Other than `reshape` and `transpose`, another similar solution: `swapaxes` in the Numpy library. The following line swaps the first axis with the 3rd one in an array `im`.

```
im.swapaxes(0,2)
```

> if a is an ndarray, then a view of a is returned; otherwise a new
>   array is created. --Quoted from [numpy-1.13.0 Docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html)

Reference

[How does numpy.swapaxes work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312670/how-does-numpy-swapaxes-work)