# Numpy / Uncertain about equivalence between np.swapaxes(array, 1,2) and np.swapaxes(array, 2,1)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am not so at ease with use of `np.swapaxes` and set aside my proudness to ask this possibly silly question.

Is it normal that considering a 3D array (for instance (2, 4, 3)), `np.swapaxes(array, 1,2)` gives same result than `np.swapaxes(array, 2,1)`?

```
array = np.array([[[1.0, -1.0, -2.0],[-1.0, -2.0, -10.0],[-2.0, -10.0, 11.0],[-10.0, 11.0, 4.0]],
                  [[1.1, -1.1, -2.1],[-1.1, -2.1, -10.1],[-2.1, -10.1, 21.1],[-10.1, 21.1, 2.1]]])

swapaxed1 = np.swapaxes(array, 1,2)
swapaxed2 = np.swapaxes(array, 2,1)
swapaxed1 == swapaxed2
```

With what dimensions for `array` would the results be different?

Thanks for your help to better understand `swapaxes` in this case. Bests,

Comment: It's a symmetric operation, it will always give the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a multidimensional array, a set of indices (non-negative integers) is used to *refer* to a particular value in that array. The number of dimensions determine the number of such integers required to uniquely specify an element. So, for a *m x n x p* 3-D array, you need a set of integers (i, j, k). It is important to note that this is an *ordered* set of integers, meaning the the order in which they are stated is important, because each integer is tied with a dimension of the array.

All `swapaxes` does is change the order of these indices for a *particular value in the array*. If you swap axes 0 and 1, the *value which was originally referred to by the set of unique integers (i, j, k)* will now be referred to by the set by (j, i, k) : the first two indices being swapped, since the axes they are tied to have been swapped.

Hence you see why it always has to be the same: it's a *swap*, and only the order of reference indices are swapped. (Atleast that's what matters in this case, atop all the stuff that numpy actually performs to achieve this.) In 2-D, a swapaxes operation is just equivalent to a transpose.

Read more about it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312670/how-does-numpy-swapaxes-work) SO discussion. In particular, GoingMyWay's answer might help you visualise it better.