# How to convert an image to array for preparing data for CNN?

Tags: python-3.x

```
img = cv2.imread('Ball.0.jpg', 0)
img = np.array(img)
print(img.size)
```

output: 7500

but I want the image size to be [50,50,3] how to do this?
The output is 50*50*3=7500

I want it in the format [50, 50, 3] for RGB.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476415/reshape-an-array-in-numpy

Comment: Cleanup code a bit add clarify O/P

Comment: what clean up?  I want the O/P to be [50, 50, 3]