# How to convert 2d numpy array to 4d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have NumPy array of float X_train shape: (6000,2304) 
I need to convert it into (6000,48,48,1)

I have read image data from CSV file which has row vector of all images.
I made NumPy array from that but I need to pass this into the convolutional neural network which needs 4D array.

Comment: What's wrong with using `.reshape`?

Comment: To extend on @PM2Ring 's comment: `a.reshape(6000,48,48,1)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshape an array in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476415/reshape-an-array-in-numpy)