# Reshape this (4,4) numpy ndarray to (2,2,4) ndarray

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have this numpy ndarray `nd` with shape `(4,4)`.

```
[
    [1.07 1.16 1.00 1.11]
    [1.13 1.19 1.11 1.17]
    [1.17 1.17 1.13 1.16]
    [1.14 1.16 1.03 1.04]
]
```

I would like to reshape it to a ndarray to `(2,2,4)` and it should look like this.

```
[
    [
        [1.07 1.16 1.00 1.11]
        [1.13 1.19 1.11 1.17]
    ]
    [
        [1.17 1.17 1.13 1.16]
        [1.14 1.16 1.03 1.04]
    ]
]
```

I am using python v3.6

Comment: What have you tried ? Simple reshape would do the job.

Comment: Yes, I felt stupid. I got confused by the answer here and thought it's going to be complicated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476415/reshape-an-array-in-numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
import numpy as np
nd = np.array([
    [1.07, 1.16, 1.00, 1.11],
    [1.13, 1.19, 1.11, 1.17],
    [1.17, 1.17, 1.13, 1.16],
    [1.14, 1.16, 1.03, 1.04]])

nd_new = np.reshape(nd, (2,2,4))
```