# How can I change the dimension of array

Tags: python, numpy

if I have a array with (10,) and (373,) for each 10 dim, how can I change this matrix into (10,373)?

thx for answering

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshape an array in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476415/reshape-an-array-in-numpy)

Comment: What's the dtype?

Comment: just np.array as the dtype

Answer (score 0):

Here's a naive solution that would work:

```
import numpy as np # you have to have numpy installed

some_array = np.random.randn(373,)
rows = 10
cols = 373
# this is your new array of desired shape:
new_array = np.empty([rows, cols])

# fill it up:
for i_th_row in range(rows):
    new_array[i_th_row,:] = some_array
```

So,

```
>>> new_array.shape
(10, 373)
```

How to install numpy can be found [here](https://scipy.org/install.html).