# How do I stack multiple columns from one single array on top of each other in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, large-data

For example, the shape of the array is 5,4.

```
a = np.random.randint(10, size= (5, 4))

a = 
[[1 4 5 0]
 [3 1 5 1]
 [4 8 0 9]
 [8 1 5 8]
 [6 4 7 4]]
```

I want the array to be reshaped as:

```
a = 
[[1 4]
 [3 1]
 [4 8]
 [8 1]
 [6 4]
 [5 0]
 [5 1]
 [0 9]
 [5 8]
 [7 4]]
```

My original array size is around 200 GB and of shape 80000*480600. I have tried to use remap mode but it is very slow.

Comment: You need to add the code what you tried, so we know what is taking too much time. There is a duplicate post somewhere else. Please check this link and see if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476415/reshape-an-array-in-numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [numpy.hsplit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html#numpy-hsplit) and [numpy.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy-concatenate):-

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(10, size= (5, 4))
>>> a
array([[8, 5, 8, 9],
       [9, 5, 6, 3],
       [5, 3, 8, 7],
       [9, 0, 9, 9],
       [0, 7, 8, 0]])
>>> t = np.hsplit(a, 2)
>>> t
[array([[8, 5],
       [9, 5],
       [5, 3],
       [9, 0],
       [0, 7]]), array([[8, 9],
       [6, 3],
       [8, 7],
       [9, 9],
       [8, 0]])]
>>> np.concatenate([t[0], t[1]])
array([[8, 5],
       [9, 5],
       [5, 3],
       [9, 0],
       [0, 7],
       [8, 9],
       [6, 3],
       [8, 7],
       [9, 9],
       [8, 0]])
```

Comment: thank you for letting me know about np.hsplit! it was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`hsplit` and `reshape` also works

```
np.reshape(np.hsplit(a, 2), (-1,2))

Out[99]:
array([[1, 4],
       [3, 1],
       [4, 8],
       [8, 1],
       [6, 4],
       [5, 0],
       [5, 1],
       [0, 9],
       [5, 8],
       [7, 4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a reshape and transpose (and a final reshape)

```
In [195]: arr = np.arange(20).reshape(5,4)                                                                   
In [196]: arr                                                                                                
Out[196]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])
In [197]: arr.reshape(5,2,2)                                                                                 
Out[197]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],

       [[12, 13],
        [14, 15]],

       [[16, 17],
        [18, 19]]])
In [198]: arr.reshape(5,2,2).transpose(1,0,2)                                                                
Out[198]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 8,  9],
        [12, 13],
        [16, 17]],

       [[ 2,  3],
        [ 6,  7],
        [10, 11],
        [14, 15],
        [18, 19]]])
```

Identifying the right transpose (or `swapaxes`) may require a bit of trial and error.

```
In [199]: arr.reshape(5,2,2).transpose(1,0,2).reshape(-1,2)                                                  
Out[199]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 8,  9],
       [12, 13],
       [16, 17],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 6,  7],
       [10, 11],
       [14, 15],
       [18, 19]])
```

The equivalent with split and concatenate:

```
In [200]: np.concatenate(np.hsplit(arr,2), axis=0)                                                           
Out[200]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 8,  9],
       [12, 13],
       [16, 17],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 6,  7],
       [10, 11],
       [14, 15],
       [18, 19]])
```

The transpose route should be faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment!