# Numpy Changing Matrix dimensions

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a 28x28 pixel image as a numpy array and its shape is (28,28) using the np.array.shape function. I want the shape to be 784x1. In other words with a NxN matrix how do you convert it to a N^2x1. Using the flatten function i get almost what I'm looking for, the shape from flatten is (784,).

Comment: `arr.reshape(784, 1)` should do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshape an array in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476415/reshape-an-array-in-numpy)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend changing your subject so it reads more like a question.  You may find that your questions are better received with a more descriptive subject.

Comment: @hpaulj gave you the best answer.  FYI, you can always add another axis to a flat array using `arr[:, np.newaxis]`.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way is to use [np.atleast_2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html)

```
np.atleast_2d(arr.flatten())
```