# Reshaping a ndarray efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a ndarray(example given below).

```
A=
[[0.1  1.1 ]
 [0.1  1.3 ]
 [0.25 1.25]
 [0.25 1.45]
 [0.37 1.37]
 [0.35 1.8 ]]
```

I want to reshape it as

```
B=
[[[0.1  1.1 ] [0.1  1.3 ]]
 [[0.25  1.25 ] [0.25  1.45 ]]
 [[0.37  1.37 ] [0.35  1.38 ]]]
```

so that doing

```
B[0] gives me [[0.1  1.1 ] [0.1  1.3 ]] and B[0][0] gives [0.1  1.1 ]
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? **Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.** See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: @AMC I know it's not a free code writing service. The issue is I am not so familiar with the reshape function so I was not able to get the correct output. From next time I will make sure that I will also post what I did..

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476415/reshape-an-array-in-numpy, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use standard [numpy reshaping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
B = A.reshape(-1, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work

```
A.reshape(3,2,2)
```