# Reshaping nested numpy array,

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array say

```
x.shape
```

(5,)

```
x[0].shape
```

(512,)
How to apply reshape so that when I get

```
x.shape
```

(5,512)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshape an array in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476415/reshape-an-array-in-numpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your content of `x` is all of the same shape:

```
x = np.stack(x)
```