# how to convert a x^2 long list to a list of shape (x,x)

Tags: python, list, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Im in python, I have a list with a length 784 (which i extracted from a 28x28 image ) and now i want to arrange it in a way i can use it in tensor-flow to be used with a trained model but the problem is that the NN needs to have a 28,28 shaped array but my current array is of shape (784,)

I tried to use some for loops for this but i have no luck in successfully creating a system to carry this out , please help

i figured out that i need to use this structure

```
for i in range(res):
   for a in range(0,res):

       mnistFormat.append(grascalePix[a]) #mnistFormat is an innitially empty list
#and grascale has my 784 grayscale pixles
```

but i cant figure out what should go in the range function of the for loop to make this possible

For example lets say i have a sample 4x4 image's pixel list >

`grayscalePix = [255,255,255,255,255,100,83,200,255,50,60,255,30,1,46,255]`

this is a **Row by Row** representation , which means the first 4 elements are the first ---- row

i want to arrange them into a list of shape (4,4)
`mnistFormat = [255,255,255,255],[255,100,83,200],[255,50,60,255],[30,1,46,255]`

Just keep in mind this is sample , the real data is 784 elements long and i dont have much experince in numpy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshape an array in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476415/reshape-an-array-in-numpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy might help you there very easily:

```
mnistFormat = np.array(grascalePix).reshape((np.sqrt(len()),-1))
```

Comment: can i also ensure that the first row of the pixel list (the first 28 values) are arranged as the first list in the mnist list(thus i want the mnist list to be a list of lists)

Comment: i looked at some reshape questions on SO but those do not place my numbers in the correct position

Comment: please provide example to demonstrate the order, in your question ofcorse

Comment: I have added the example

Comment: i think the reshape gives what you want, maybe what you mean is to turn your result to list so just do `arr.tolist()`

Comment: okay i didnt use arr.tolist() but your answere works so tq for that